# Google speech to text in React native

Tags: android, react-native, speech-to-text

I want to show google speech to text to search items in my react native project. But I am not able to find any proper documentation regarding this. I already used `react-native-voice` but I am not getting a result like a google. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `react-native-speech-to-text-android` to get your desired result.

```
import SpeechToText from 'react-native-google-speech-to-text';

const speechToTextHandler = async () => {

    let speechToTextData = null;
        try {
            speechToTextData = await SpeechToText.startSpeech('Try saying something', 'en_IN');
            console.log('speechToTextData: ', speechToTextData);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);
        }
}
```